# Control device labels in /dev

Tags: linux, dev

I have an HP xw8200 workstation running linux with two small, fast SCSI drives hooked up to the onboard LSI SCSI controller.  The drives get labeled /dev/sda & /dev/sdb in /dev, respectively.  I have a large SATA disk that I want to add to the system to store data, but every time I connect it, it's /dev gets assigned sda & the two scsi drives are assigned sdb,c, which messes with the boot procedure.  How can I get this SATA drive to use sdc?

Comment: Why are you not using labels or UUIDs for boot?

Comment: I am using LVM & that is how fstab was generated.

Comment: @churnd You can modify fstab to use UUID or labels, UUID=[uuid] and LABEL=[label] respectively. The UUID can be detected with `blkid` (run it as root). The label can be found with `ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/`

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to use [udev](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) (that daemon that controls the /dev filesystem) to write some rules that change the /dev entry for the SATA, and then modify your fstab to accomidate this.

You can find out how to write a udev entry (the page mostly covers USB devices, but that and the man pages should help you get a good idea on how to do it) by following the link above.

[HackADay](http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/) might expand your knowledge on udev rules a little bit as well.